# Orthonormal complete set of functions on general domains

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Consider a domain $D \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with piecewise linear boundary,
where loosely speaking, by piecewise linear boundary I mean a boundary that is composed of straight lines, for example :
[image]

Is there any way to find an orthonormal complete set of functions on $L^2(D, \mathbb{R}^2)$ ?

In general, is it possible to find such function 'bases' on arbitrary domains ?

Comment: Good question! I don't know am explicit answer, but if you take a self adjoint compact operator on this domain, it  will have and orthonormal basis of eigenfunctions. Similarly, you could consider the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian (with Dirichlet boundary conditions), for example. These can be computed numerically quite easily.